API Request body is fetched from Excel in res Assured API but not able to fetch key and value and validate each key value
Excel Driven Rest Assured API Automation:
Able to fetch the request body from the Excel and getting the success response but the below scenario need to perform.
1.I am not able to fetch each key and value of the JSON body
2.I am looking to validate each value like not empty, string or integer accepted of the JSON body
Excel Sheet Pix:

dataTestDriven.java
package ExcelDriven.ExcelDrivenAPI;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.NumberToTextConverter;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class dataTestDriven {
    
    //Identify Testcases column by scanning the entire 1st row
    //once column is identified then scan entire testcase column to identify purchase testcase row
    //after you grab purchase testcase row = pull all the data of that row and feed into test
    
    public ArrayList<String> getData(String testcaseName,String sheetname) throws IOException
    {
        //fileInputStream argument
                ArrayList<String> a=new ArrayList<String>();
                
                FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("C://Users\\shahnawaz\\Desktop\\addbook.xlsx");
                XSSFWorkbook workbook=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
                
                int sheets=workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
                for(int i=0;i<sheets;i++)
                {
                    if(workbook.getSheetName(i).equalsIgnoreCase(sheetname))
                            {
                    XSSFSheet sheet=workbook.getSheetAt(i);
                    //Identify Testcases column by scanning the entire 1st row
                    
                     Iterator<Row>  rows= sheet.iterator();// sheet is collection of rows
                    Row firstrow= rows.next();
                    Iterator<Cell> ce=firstrow.cellIterator();//row is collection of cells
                    int k=0;
                    int column = 0;
                while(ce.hasNext())
                {
                    Cell value=ce.next();
                    
                    if(value.getStringCellValue().equalsIgnoreCase("TestCases"))
                        //TestCases //header name
                    {
                        column=k;
                        
                    }
                    
                    k++;
                }
                System.out.println(column);
                
                ////once column is identified then scan entire testcase column to identify purchase testcase row
                while(rows.hasNext())
                {
                    
                    Row r=rows.next();
                    
                    if(r.getCell(column).getStringCellValue().equalsIgnoreCase(testcaseName))
                    {
                        
                        ////after you grab purchase testcase row = pull all the data of that row and feed into test
                        
                        Iterator<Cell>  cv=r.cellIterator();
                        while(cv.hasNext())
                        {
                        Cell c= cv.next();
                        if(c.getCellType()==CellType.STRING)
                        {
                            
                        a.add(c.getStringCellValue());
                        }
                        else{
                            
                            a.add(NumberToTextConverter.toText(c.getNumericCellValue()));
                        
                        }
                        }
                    }
                    
                
                }
            
                
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                            }
                }
                return a;
                
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        
    }

}


NewExcelDriven.java:
package ExcelDriven.ExcelDrivenAPI;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;
import io.restassured.path.xml.XmlPath;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

//import resources.*;
public class NewExcelDriven {

    static String place_id;
    @Test
    public void addBook() throws IOException
    {
        dataTestDriven d=new dataTestDriven();
        ArrayList data=d.getData("TestAddBook","AdBookRest");
        //TestAddBook// test cases name of excel
        //AdBookRest// sheetname
                
            
        Object map=data.get(1);
        //System.out.println(map.put("name", data.get(1)));
        
    /*  HashMap<String, Object>  map2 = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("lat", "12");
        map.put("lng", "34");
        map.put("location", map2);*/
        
        
        RestAssured.baseURI="http://216.10.245.166";
        String resp = given().log().all().
                header("Content-Type","application/json").
        body(map).
        when().
        post("/Library/Addbook.php").
        then().log().all().assertThat().statusCode(200).
        extract().response().asString();
        //System.out.println(resp);
                                            
        
    // Create a place =response (place id)
        
        // delete Place = (Request - Place id)  
        
    }
    @Test
    public void addplace() throws IOException
    {
        dataTestDriven done=new dataTestDriven();
        ArrayList dataone=done.getData("GoogleAddPlace","GoogleAPI");
        //TestAddBook// test cases name of excel
        //AdBookRest// sheetname
                            
        String endpointurl=(String) dataone.get(1);
        String resource=(String) dataone.get(2);
        Object bodyjson=dataone.get(3);
                                                                    
        //HashMap<String, Object>  mapt = new HashMap<>();                  
        
        //System.out.println(map.put("name", data.get(1)));
        
    /*  HashMap<String, Object>  map2 = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("lat", "12");
        map.put("lng", "34");
        map.put("location", map2);*/        
    
        RestAssured.baseURI=endpointurl;
                                
        String responeone = given().log().all().
                header("Content-Type","application/json").
        body(bodyjson).
        when().
        post(resource).
        then().log().all().assertThat().statusCode(200).
        extract().response().asString();
        //System.out.println(resp);
        JsonPath js=new JsonPath(responeone);
         place_id=js.get("place_id");
                    
    }
    @Test
    public void deleteplace() throws IOException
    {
        dataTestDriven delt=new dataTestDriven();
        ArrayList dltvar=delt.getData("DeleteAddPlace","GoogleAPI");
        //TestAddBook// test cases name of excel
        //AdBookRest// sheetname
                            
        String dlendpointurl=(String) dltvar.get(1);
        String dlresource=(String) dltvar.get(2);
        RestAssured.baseURI=dlendpointurl;
        //System.out.println("delete place id fetch" +place_id);
        given().log().all().header("Content-Type","application/json").body("{\r\n"
                + "    \"place_id\":\""+place_id+"\"\r\n"
                + "}").
        when().post(dlresource).then().log().all().assertThat().statusCode(200).extract().response().asString();
                                            
    }
    
}

